# Yearly renewing database table

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a PHP/MySQL based Office Automation System. 
I have an issue with Employee's Leave section.

```
emp_leave(EmpID,annual_leaves,casual_leaves,duty_leaves)
```

Above table will store the balance of each employee's leave.

Issue is, I can use the above table for the year of 2017 without any issue. 
 But the problem is,  on 1st day of 2018, all the leave info should reset (But I want all the data in 2017). 
What should I do? 
Is it good to have separate table for year 2018 (like emp_leave2018) or is there any other good way?

Comment: add a timestamp column and manipulate the records according to this column?

Comment: I'd be tempted to design the system to optionally allow leave to run over into January

Answer (score 0):

Add new column for date or timestamp and filter as per year requirement.